# Сборник задач по Java

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!

Посоветуйте ссылки по основам *Java*, где можно больше попробать с примерами и поразбираться с кодом к каждой теме?

Где можно скачать сборник задач по *JAVA*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Вот](http://codingbat.com/) еще хороший сборник задач по Java Fundamentals.

Answer (score 4):

Что касается примеров, есть замечательный сайт http://java2s.com/Code/Java/CatalogJava.htm с кучей примеров как по самому языку, так и по различным библиотекам и фрэймворкам.

А по задачам можно попробовать чтото типа такого ресурса http://acm.timus.ru можно решать задачи и отправлять на проверку на разных языках, в том числе и на java.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ "DigitalDemiurge"

Answer (score 2):

[javarush.ru](http://javarush.ru) определенно является хорошим сборником задач, больше 1000 штук, да еще и с автоматической проверкой

Comment: Теперь это платный ресурс и (имхо) не стоит своих денег (стоит покупать, если по акции за ~6 000 руб., но не за 18 000 руб.)